# phone Notification Xamarin sqlite

Tags: sqlite, azure, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am a novice in Xamarin.

I have list of string in my sql lite database and I am looking for a way to create notification.

For example after 30 minute , on your phone you have notification about some string words in your database.

like : "hey ! your have this word1 word2 word3 word4 on your database"

Or if you have a better solution , I will take .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Notifications are well documented for both iOS and Android.  I suggest you take the time to research this on your own, and then if you have specific questions come back and ask them.

Comment: @Jason , thanks , I am looking for crossform solution because I have only find for Ios or android

Comment: Jason is right.  You need to develop specific version for Android and iOS because is not cross platform (or you need to find a library that do the job for you)